# Difficulties with `agrep(..., fixed=F)`

Tags: r

In `?agrep` (`grep` with fuzzy matching) it mentions that I can set the argument `fixed=FALSE` to let my pattern be interpreted as a regular expression.

However, I can't get it to work!

```
agrep('(asdf|fdsa)', 'asdf', fixed=F)
# integer(0)
```

The above *should* match as the regular expression "(asdf|fdsa)" *exactly* matches the test string "asdf" in this case.

To confirm:

```
grep('(asdf|fdsa)', 'asdf', fixed=F)
# 1 : it does match with grep
```

And even more confusingly, `adist` correctly gives the distance between the pattern and string as 0, meaning that `agrep` should *definitely* return 1 rather than `integer(0)` (there's no possibility that 0 is greater than the default `max.dist = 0.1`).

```
adist('(asdf|fdsa)', 'asdf', fixed=F)
#      [,1]
# [1,]    0
```

**Why is this not working? Is there something I don't understand? A workaround?**
I'm happy to use `adist`, but am not entirely sure how to convert `agrep`'s default `max.distance=0.1` parameter to `adist`'s corresponding parameter.

(yes, I'm stuck on an old computer that can't do better than R 2.15.2)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i686-redhat-linux-gnu (32-bit)    
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
 [3] LC_TIME=en_AU.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_AU.utf8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_AU.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.utf8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                LC_NAME=C                
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: I am unable to explain this behaviour as well, but `aregexc` seem to work. `aregexc('asdf|fdsa', 'asdf')` (which takes default `fixed = FALSE`) and does regexp by default. But surprisingly `fixed=TRUE` here with `aregexc` gets back to the same issue.

Comment: Where did you get `aregexc` from? I'm guessing this is in a newer version of R than I have?

Comment: It mentions under the help page of `?agrep`, but yes I do have R 3.0.0. your problem seems to be with `|`. Because `agrep('la[sb]y', 'lazy', fixed=FALSE)` works.

Comment: It's `aregexec`. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Thanks for `aregexec` (my `?agrep` does not mention it).

Comment: Okay, I really need a coffee. It doesn't mention in `?agrep`. Once again sorry about that. I've now no idea where I saw it! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr: `agrep(..., fixed=F)` does not seem to work with the '|' character. Use `aregexec`.**

Upon further investigation, I think this is a bug, and that `agrep(..., fixed=F)` does **not** seem to work with '|' regexes (although `adist(..., fixed=F)` does).

To elaborate, note that

```
adist('(asdf|fdsa)', 'asdf', fixed=T) # 7
nchar('(asdf|fdsa)')                  # 11
```

If 'asdf' were `agrep`'d to the *non-regular-expression* string '(asdf|fdsa)', then it would have distance 7.

On that note:

```
agrep('(asdf|fdsa)', 'asdf', fixed=F, max.distance=7) # 1
agrep('(asdf|fdsa)', 'asdf', fixed=F, max.distance=6) # integer(0)
```

These are the results I'd expect if `fixed=T`. If `fixed=F`, my regex would match 'asdf' *exactly* and the distance would be 0, so I'd always get a result of '1' back out of `agrep`.

So it looks **`agrep(pattern, x, fixed=F)` does not work**, i.e. it actually regardes `fixed` as TRUE for this sort of pattern.

As @Arun mentions, it might just be '|' regexes that don't work. For example,  `agrep('la[sb]y', 'lazy', fixed=FALSE)` *does* work as expected.

---

#### EDIT: Workaround (thanks @Arun)

The function `aregexec` appears to work.

```
> aregexec('(asdf|fdsa)', 'asdf', fixed=F)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This has (finally) been fixed in the R sources "trunk" / R-devel") and R-patched which will become R 3.5.1  early July 2018.