# How to get around a bug in the agrep function regular expression logic in R?

Tags: r, regex, fuzzy-search, agrep

So I've run into a small bug/feature in R where the agrep function does not accept the "|" character as valid regular expression logic ([others have had this problem too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871702/difficulties-with-agrep-fixed-f)), when used in the argument.

I'm trying to do a fuzzy match of 30 different, relatively unique names in one character vector (ListofUniqueNames) against a list of over 380,000 different names in a data-frame column (MasterList$Names), and get an output of all the matching names. I was able to accomplish this fine for exact matches using grep via

```
grep(paste(ListofUniqueNames,collapse="|"),MasterList$Names, value=TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

However, this approach doesn't work for agrep due to the problem listed above. How can I accomplish this same task but with fuzzy matching?

Comment: The `grep` statement above actually works.  Did you mean to use `agrep` instead of `grep`

Comment: The statement is an example of a grep function that worked for exact matches. However `agrep(paste(ListofUniqueNames,collapse="|"),MasterList$Names, value=TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE, fixed=FALSE)` does not work. Neither does `agrep('(asdf|fdsa)', 'asdf', fixed=F)`

Comment: interesting stuff: `agrep("asdf", "(asdf|fdsa)")` and then `agrep("(asdf|fdsa)", "asdf", max.distance=.55)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `agrep` one by one for each pattern,
and then combine the results:

```
unlist(lapply(ListofUniqueNames, function(x) agrep(x, MasterList$Names, value=T, ignore.case = TRUE)))
```